# How to edit html in sources in inspect element?

Tags: html, inspect-element

I noticed that I can't change the html code in sources of inspect element. I can't place my cursor inside or type. If anyonw knows why and how I can change it, please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want to change the HTML code in inspect element right-click what you want to edit and there will be an option called edit as HTML. I hope this helps :D

[image]